# Concurrent Streams Does't Print Anything to Console

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

I'm trying to build an example concerning using the `Stream.concurrently` method in fs2. I'm developing the producer/consumer pattern, using a `Queue` as the shared state:

```scala
import cats.effect.std.{Queue, Random}

object Fs2Tutorial extends IOApp {
  val random: IO[Random[IO]] = Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO]
  val queue: IO[Queue[IO, Int]] = Queue.bounded[IO, Int](10)

  val producer: IO[Nothing] = for {
    r <- random
    q <- queue
    p <-
      r.betweenInt(1, 11)
      .flatMap(q.offer)
      .flatTap(_ => IO.sleep(1.second))
      .foreverM
  } yield p

  val consumer: IO[Nothing] = for {
    q <- queue
    c <- q.take.flatMap { n =>
      IO.println(s"Consumed $n")
    }.foreverM
  } yield c

  val concurrently: Stream[IO, Nothing] = Stream.eval(producer).concurrently(Stream.eval(consumer))

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    concurrently.compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

I expect the program to print some `"Consumed n"`, for some `n`. However, the program prints nothing to the console.

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong with the above code?

You are not using the same `Queue` in the consumer and in the producer, rather each of them is creating its own new independent `Queue` *(the same happens with `Random` BTW)*

This is a common mistake made by newbies who don't grasp yet the main principles behind a data type like `IO`

When you do `val queue: IO[Queue[IO, Int]] = Queue.bounded[IO, Int](10)` you are saying that `queue` is a program that when evaluated will produce a value of type `Queue[IO, Unit]`, that is the point of all this.
The program become a value, and as any value you can manipulate it in any ways to produce new values, for example using `flatMap` so when both `consumer` & `producer` crate a new program by `flatMapping` `queue` they both create new independent programs / values.

You can fix that code like this:

```scala
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import cats.effect.std.{Queue, Random}
import cats.syntax.all._
import fs2.Stream

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Fs2Tutorial extends IOApp.Simple {  
  override final val run: IO[Unit] = {
    val resources =
      (
        Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO],
        Queue.bounded[IO, Int](10)
      ).tupled
    
    val concurrently =
      Stream.eval(resources).flatMap {
        case (random, queue) =>
          val producer = 
            Stream
              .fixedDelay[IO](1.second)
              .evalMap(_ => random.betweenInt(1, 11))
              .evalMap(queue.offer)

        val consumer =
          Stream.fromQueueUnterminated(queue).evalMap(n => IO.println(s"Consumed $n"))
        
        producer.concurrently(consumer)
      }
    
    concurrently.interruptAfter(10.seconds).compile.drain >> IO.println("Finished!")
  }
}
```

*(You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6yv5W21mRcWS9KOL3d4T2g/9))*.

---

PS: I would recommend you to look into the *"Programs as Values"* Series from Fabio Labella: https://systemfw.org/archive.html

Comment: Luis, thanks a lot for the response and the link to Fabio's posts.